# Handling multiple useEffect hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am calling useEffect hook multiple times in a component

```
useEffect(() => {
  getData(id);
}, [getData, id]);

const reqBody = useMemo(
  () => ({
    item: data?.item,
  }), [data?.item]
);

useEffect(() => {
  if (data?.item) {
    getAnotherData(reqBody);
  }
}, [getAnotherData]);
```

As seen in the code snippet, the first useEffect hook calls a function called `getData` which stores the data in redux store and the reqBody of the function `getAnotherData` in the second hook depends on the first hook.
Therefore, the second hook runs even if the `data` in the store is not updated yet resulting in multiple api calls.
How can I avoid this so that the function `getAnotherData` is called only when the `data` in the store is updated?

Answer (score 0):

Use `data` in the dependency array instead of `getAnotherData` in the second `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getData(id);
}, [getData, id]);

const reqBody = useMemo(
  () => ({
    item: data?.item,
  }), [data?.item]
);

useEffect(() => {
  if (data?.item) {
    getAnotherData(reqBody);
  }
}, [data]);
```